# animate() not working with dynamic css() properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, dynamic

I was working on making my animations work dynamically for various elements when I ran into this problem (right when I was about to finish too). **I can't animate properties using the JQuery css() method**. I was able to get the animation **working with hard coded values** for the height, width, and top properties. Here's the snippet:

```
    function shrinkSection(section){
    var elem = section.SectionID;
    $(elem).find(".content").fadeOut(500);
    $(elem)
        .animate({top: $(elem).css('top'), height: $(elem).css('height')}, 500)
        .animate({width: $(elem).css('width')}, {duration: 500,
        complete: function() {
        $(elem).find(".icon").fadeIn(500);
        $(elem).addClass("active");
                }
        });
}
```

**`console.log()`** reveals that **`$(elem).css('[PROPERTY]')`** **IS** returning the **correct css value**. Any ideas why this won't work?

Comment: Well, if you animate the element from its current `top` to its current `top`, nothing should change, shouldn't it?

Comment: Notice that it's shrinkSection(). I have another method (growSection())that expands the element to a larger dimension and then this shrinks it back to its original size.

Comment: But `$(elem).css('height')` returns current, expanded height.

Comment: Aaahhhhhh you are right! I was thinking that the .css() function refers to the value I have set in the style sheet! What a goof...Well, then my next question is: "How do I refer to the value set in the style sheet?"

Answer (score 0):

The animate() method queues the effects and waits till the first effect animation is finished to start the second one, so they are serially applied. From jquery docs:

> **queue** (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean or String
>   A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string. When a custom queue name is used the animation does not automatically start; you must call .dequeue("queuename") to start it.

If you want the animations to happen in "parallel", you can do:

```
$(elem).find(".content").fadeOut(500);

if( $(elem).length )
    $(elem)
        .animate( { top: $(elem).css('top'), height: $(elem).css('height')}, 
                  { duration: 500, 
                    queue: false, 
                    complete: function() { alert('callback!!'); } } 
                )
        .animate( { width: $(elem).css('width')}, 
                  { duration: 500,
                    queue: false, 
                    complete: function() {
                        $(elem).find(".icon").fadeIn(500);
                        $(elem).addClass("active");
                    }   
                });
else 
    alert("No elem found!!");
```

Notice in the example, that you could check that the element `elem` on which you apply the effect is actually found by jquery.
This way you track possible DOM selector problems also.

Comment: I actually don't want them to occur in parallel so what I have is fine in terms of queuing. The problem is that the value I am returning from the $(elem).css('[PROPERTY]') is not being accepted by the animate function. So "height: '60px'" animates while "height: $(elem).css('height')" (which returns 60px) does not.